# Copy output of bash command to system clipboard?

Tags: buffers, external-command, ex-mode

If I run:

```
:w !node
```

It will take my current buffer and send it to stdin and run the code in node.

If I run:

```
:redir @+ | echo "bob" | redir END
```

It ends up on the system clipboard.

But if I want to copy the output to the clipboard, by running:

```
:redir @+ | w !node | redir END
```

It seems the input from the current buffer does not reach node, and that it tries to run redir as a command from bash for some reason.

```
:redir @+ | w !node | redir END
/bin/bash: redir: command not found
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:790:14)

shell returned 127
```

Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything after `!` will be a command, including `|`. So what you're running is:

```
:redir @+
:w !node | redir END
```

This makes sense, since using `|` is shell commands is common to pipe output.

The easiest workaround is to use multiple lines:

```
:redir @+
:w !node
:redir END
```

or you can use `:execute` to work around this:

```
:redir @+ | :exe 'w !node' | redir END
```